# Can you read SMS on a computer directly from a SIM-card?

Tags: gateway, sms, gsm, sim

I'm looking for a way to recieve and parse incoming SMS on a computer in an automated manner. I currently have ~100 SIM-cards that would ideally be connected all at once.

- Is this realistic?
- What would it cost? (As an estimate)

I have heard about GSM gateways, which sometimes have support for multiple SIM-cards.

- Are these the right way to go?
- Are they just plug and play?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to start by educating yourself as to what a GSM modem is and how the telephony stack works.  The specific devices you will be interested in can be found by searching "bulk SMS modem".  You should probably buy a small single sim one and learn how to control it before going to the bigger products but that is only my opinion.  What would it cost?  Search the thing I said to search and answer that yourself.